# Why HDInsight Cluster can not add Blob Storage account as data source in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

As a newbie of Azure, I plan to build a cloud computing service with a free trial account.

I first created a **Storage account**. The *Deployment model* is **Resource Manager** as recommended so that I chose *Blob storage* as the **Account kind**.

Then I created an **HDInsight cluster**. But in the **Data source configuration**, the aforementioned **Blob storage account** can not be selected but with a warning - *Could not reach the storage!*. However, If I have created the **Storage account** with **Classic** as the *Deployment model*, the created Storage account can be selected as the **Data source**.

Anyone have any idea about why is it so?

Thanks in advance! I got stuck up here for long time

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected 'Resource Manger' as the Deployment model, then the storage account should be of type 'general purpose azure blob storage account', you might have created azure blob only storage type account.